# df.ix not working , whats the right iloc method?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-structures

This is my program-

```
#n= no. of days
def ATR(df , n):
  df['H-L'] = abs(df['High'] - df['Low'])
  df['H-PC'] = abs(df['High'] - df['Close'].shift(1))
  df['L-PC'] = abs(df['Low'] - df['Close'].shift(1)) 
  df['TR']=df[['H-L','H-PC','L-PC']].max(axis=1)
  df['ATR'] = np.nan
  df.ix[n-1,'ATR']=df['TR'][:n-1].mean()
  for i in range(n , len(df)):
    df['ATR'][i] = (df['ATR'][i-1]*(n-1) + df['TR'][i])/n
  return
```

A warning shows up

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ix
```

I tried to replace it with iloc:

```
 df.iloc[df.index[n-1],'ATR'] = df['TR'][:n-1].mean()
```

But this time another error pops up :

```
only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Converting code is a pain and we have all been there...

```
df.ix[n-1,'ATR'] = df['TR'][:n-1].mean()
```

should become

```
df['ATR'].iloc[n-1] = df['TR'][:n-1].mean()
```

Hope this fits the bill